# Different checkout form based on user or role

Tags: 7, commerce

As described, in the docs [Checkout Form Builder](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/checkout-form-builder). This is how you modify the checkout flow. Is it possible to have different checkout flows based on role or user?

For example;

- If a teller is logged in. There is no need to collect show account information, or billing.
- If a customer is logged in. It will display those panes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think something along the lines of this should work.  If you have a whole load of these I'd put them in custom module. Otherwise template.php

```
/***
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter
*/

function myform_form_theformid_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  global $user;
  if (in_array('teller', $user->roles)) {
  unset($form['account_information']);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably by implementing hook_form_alter(), you could check for the currently logged-in user's role and make form changes depending on what role.